# IDE for client side web app Visual Studio or VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio, web, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm looking to build a web app with HTML, TS, SASS, Jquery.
I looked into using Visual Studio for this but it looks like all web projects would require some server side code?
Should I use VS Code instead? Even though I have more experience with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only going to use HTML, TS, SASS and Jquery, and other client side technologies, VS Code is more than enough.

Some advantages of VS Code are:

- It is 100% Free
- Lightweight. Uses less computer resources (Memmory, processor)
- You can run it in Windows, Linux and MacOs
- It can be perzonalized a lot throught extensions.

Can you work with those technologies (HTML, TS, SASS, and JQuery) with Visual Studio? Yes. However, considering that it requires more resources and it does not give you any advantage than using VS Code, using VS Code is a better option.

In the future, if your needs require it, you always will be able to install Visual Studio.